# HTML dropdown box with MySQL in form

Tags: mysql

I have PHP coding that works but I have had no luck transferring this to a HTML form.  Any advise?

```
<?php
$db_host =  "localhost";
$db_username  =  "combsb_combsb";
$db_pass =  "pat60086";
$db_name =  "combsb_sample";

@mysql_connect ("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No Database");

Echo"Successful Connection";


$sql = "SELECT compname FROM Crew";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='compname'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['compname'] . "'>" . $row['compname'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";


?>
```

Comment: You would like your db items in the table to populate the select box?

Comment: Yep, a advice, do not use MySQL library to access data :) show the error you have.

Comment: Tell us what problem you're actually having. Asking for general advice because you "had no luck" doesn't give anyone much to go on. You'll get much better answers if you post with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd make sure to add the HTML boilerplate around your PHP. Then I think you mean mysql_fetch_row instead of mysql_fetch_array. Your final file should look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<?php
// *Cut out for brevity, remember to paste back in* 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>

    <form action="" method="POST">

<?php
echo "<select name='compname'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['compname'] . "'>" . $row['compname'] . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Post your output / errors next time or if this doesn't work